# Как отключить генерацию robots.txt в Yoast seo?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, seo, yoast

Всем привет.
Как отключить генерацию robots.txt в новом Yoast seo?
Мне нужно чтоб другой плагин сгенерировал роботсы для основного домена и поддоменов, но yoast перетирает файлы которые генерит другой плагин. Как отключить генерацию? Не нашел такой опции

Answer (score 0):

Yoast не создает физический файл `robots.txt`, пока вы сами не введете его содержание в админке Yoast и не нажмете "сохранить".

Когда физический файл не существует, Yoast создает виртуальный файл, который выводится по запросу `site.test/robots.txt`. Виртуальный файл имеет такой вид:

```
# START YOAST BLOCK
# ---------------------------
User-agent: *
Disallow:

Sitemap: https://site.test/sitemap_index.xml
# ---------------------------
# END YOAST BLOCK
```

Если ваш плагин создаёт виртуальный файл "на лету", то, возможно, Yoast замещает его своим, приведённым выше. Происходит это потому, что код Yoast работает на хуке 'robots_txt' с приоритетом 99999.

Вы всегда можете сделать следующее.

1. Отключить Yoast
2. Открыть в браузере ссылку `your_site.ru/robots.txt`
3. Скопировать содержимое экрана в браузере
4. Создать файл robots.txt в корне диска и вставить туда это содержимое
5. Включить Yoast снова

Вместо 4 и 5 можно сделать так

- включить Yoast
- на странице `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpseo_tools&tool=file-editor` создать robots.txt, вставить туда ранее скопированный код и сохранить